# How do I parse a website in python once I know its url?

Tags: python

If I know the url of a wiki site , How do I use python to parse the contents of it ?

Answer (score 10):

This is a very broad question, but the first things to reach for are [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), which will handle the downloading part, and [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which will do the parsing.  Gluing them together and writing the code to actually extract information from the parse tree is up to you.

Comment: +1 for @Zack It is really a broad question. @mekaspersky Search SO itself for what you want exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) as well.